# Cannot play videos with AVPlayer when NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent is true

Tags: ios, swift, plist, avplayer

I have a very small application with `AVPlayer`. I am using the following code to play a video:

```
if let urlToPlay = URL(string: "http://some_video.m3u8") {

    self.player = AVPlayer.init(url: urlToPlay)
    self.player!.play()
}
```

I also added some lines into the file "Info.plist" to be able to play videos with HTTP schemas:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

And it works fine. But later I found a flag called `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`. I don't have any `WKWebView` or `UIWebView` instances in my application, so I supposed that using of this flag will not lead to any crashes or errors in my application. Now my file "Info.plist" has this fragment:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

And player is not working. Could someone explain me why it happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For media loading through AVFoundation Add the key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia` and set it to true.

According to the documentation:

> In iOS 10 and later, and macOS 10.12 and later, the value of this key
>   is ignored—resulting in an effective value for this key of its default
>   value of NO—if any of the following keys are present in your app’s
>   Info.plist file:
>
> NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia, 
>   NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent,
>   NSAllowsLocalNetworking

Note that setting arbitrary loads are not encouraged in production and these flags triggers an AppStore review and requires justification for doing so.

For further reading visit [ATS Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33)

Comment: Thank you for help. However when I set both NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia and NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true playback is not working. But why?

Comment: The documentation says if you add any other key, NSAllowsArbitraryLoads is ignored.

Comment: I also found in the documentation that NSAllowsArbitraryLoads will be overridden. But what if I set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true in  "Info.plist"? Why playback works only when I set NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia without NSAllowsArbitraryLoads?

Comment: Because whatever is the value of NSAllowArbitraryLoads, if any other key is present its default value i.e. NO is read.

Answer (score 0):

```
Also Create a AVPlayerViewController object to play the Video.

 let video = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath:path))
 let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
 videoPlayer.player = video
 present(videoPlayer, animated:true, completion: {
        video.play()
   })

Hope this will helps for you.
```

Comment: My question is about a problem with the file 'Info.plist", I can play videos if they are not http-based.