# WKWebview can not load Video Player

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm now developing an app that uses wkwebview to load some movie website.
But I face some problems.
For example, wkwebview can not load video player in https://fmovies.wtf/home but SafariViewController can.
Would you please help me to solve this problem.
Many thanks

Here is screenshot

[image]

Comment: video player link not open in safari can you check again

Comment: It looks like the web page is loading, but it's possible that something is missing from the configuration of your `WKWebView`. You can try to enable javascript like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47038285/1440005, and you might also want to take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50506476/1440005 that deals with allowing arbitrary loads (maybe you also have http content that needs to be loaded by the page).